# keras input reshape , do I flatten the input?

Tags: keras

Ok I'm working with keras, sequential.
I have a dataset, an array of 500 samples of 10 units each.

How do I feed it into the model ?
Am I supposed to flatten it to 1D and specify batch size as 10 ?

I have additional data associated with each sample. Which I don't need to feed into the model but need to keep track of as it is related to the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to the model should specify the size of one sample, you don't need to flatten the input. In your case, the input size should be (10,). That is one sample has 10 values; the comma symbolizes a row is 1d.

The batch size can be anything you want/ what performs best for your dataset.

Comment: my model is complaining that it is "expecting to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 500 arrays"

Comment: update your question with more details about the model  with example code and errors + example dataset, how does a sample look like?